# Undefined symbol when implementing template with restriction on parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a lightweight class to deal with csv format files. One of the functions is `sum` which is getting the sum of a specific column. It receives a numeric type as parameter and returns the sum of that type. So I write it in template style. I did it like this:

```
#define IS_NUMERIC_VALUE (  std::is_same<T,int>::value || std::is_same<T,long>::value || std::is_same<T,double>::value || std::is_same<T,float>::value || std::is_same<T,size_t>::value )
template < class T, class = typename std::enable_if< IS_NUMERIC_VALUE >::type > 
int sum(T& get_sum);

template < class T, class > 
int sum(T& get_sum)
{
    int iRet {1};
    //doing sth here
    return iRet;
}
```

It works well but when I was trying to move the implementation part to a `.cpp` file, I got an error of *undefined symbol xxx*. I can't put it in one file because I have many other similar ones. What is the problem?

Comment: consider using "using" instead of macros

Comment: Consider [`is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) instead of your macro. Also your problem has nothing to do with your title...